# checking for the presence of an obj in an js array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array:

```js
const temp=[{x:10,y:15},{x:45,y:50}];
```

and an object:

```js
const obj=[{x:45,y:50}]
```

How to check if obj is contained in temp. I used `temp.includes(obj)` but it returns `false`. Why is that and what is correct method to do something like this?

Comment: Even without the issue that objects are compared by *identity*, which isn't how people intuitively expect them to be compared (`temp.includes(obj[0])` would also fail), `obj` is an *array* that definitely isn't in `temp`, an array of *objects*.

Comment: Take a look at [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: @jonsharpe how do you compare by values then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not working because of *references*. When you initialize an object, the value of the variable is not the object itself, but a reference to it. That's why `{} === {}` is `false` and `obj === obj` is `true`.

If you only care about `x` and `y`, you can use

```js
const temp=[{x:10,y:15},{x:45,y:50}],
obj = {x:45,y:50};
console.log( temp.some( o => o.x === obj.x && o.y === obj.y ) );
```

If you care about all own enumerable properties, use [Yevgen Gorbunkov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62755130/9253414). **Edit:** That answer was deleted. It used `Array.prototype.find()` along with `Object.keys` to compare the value for each key.